# python input taking integer while specified for string

Tags: python, while-loop

I am practicing python and I was writing a small program in which I have to ask them for their name, but I tried to make sure they aren't entering any numbers. So when I code like in **Number 1** it doesn't take int, but it returns **Hello (int that I tried)**, and when I have the code setup like **Number 2**, it works. So I am doing something wrong in defining the asker function, please help me understand why having a function allows the integer to be stored even after I have **isalpha()**

.
.

**Number 1**

```
def asker(phrase, name):
  while not name.isalpha():
    print(phrase)
    name = str(input())
  


#Introducing the Game and asking for first player's name
print('Hello! lets play lastLetterWord game')
print("-------------------------------------------")
print('Please enter your name')
x = str(input())
asker("Please enter your name. Only alphabets.", x)
print("-------------------------------------------")
print("Hello " + x)
print("-------------------------------------------")
```

[Terminal result of trying code of Number 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ku449.png)
..

---

**Number 2**

```
#Introducing the Game and asking for first player's name
print('Hello! lets play lastLetterWord game')
print("-------------------------------------------")
print('Please enter your name')
x = str(input())
while not x.isalpha():
    print("Please enter your name. Only alphabets.")
    x = str(input())
print("-------------------------------------------")
print("Hello " + x)
print("-------------------------------------------")
print("What is your friend's name?")
print("-------------------------------------------")
```

[Terminal results of trying Number 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3N6Xm.png)

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not saving the result from the function. Try:

```
 def asker(phrase, name):
    while not name.isalpha():
        print(phrase)
        name = str(input())
    return name


#Introducing the Game and asking for first player's name
print('Hello! lets play lastLetterWord game')
print("-------------------------------------------")
print('Please enter your name')
x = str(input())
x = asker("Please enter your name. Only alphabets.", x)
print("-------------------------------------------")
print("Hello " + x)
print("-------------------------------------------")
```

Comment: thank you @Eli Harold

Answer (score 0):

Your `asker` needs to `return` the name rather than taking it as a parameter (assigning to `name` inside the body of the function doesn't affect the argument you passed to it from outside the function):

```
def asker(phrase):
    name = ""
    while not name.isalpha():
        print(phrase)
        name = input()
    return name
```

and then you can do:

```
x = asker("Please enter your name. Only alphabets.")
```

and now `x` is whatever name the user entered.

If you want to have two different versions of the prompt (one the first time, one with an error message if the user gets it wrong the first time), you could do that in `asker` like this:

```
def asker(phrase, error_msg):
    name = input(f"{phrase}\n")
    while not name.isalpha():
        name = input(f"{phrase} {error_msg}\n")
    return name
```

and then call it like:

```
x = asker("Please enter your name.", "Only alphabets.")
```

*Note that even if the user enters a digit to `input()`, the result is always still a `str`, not an `int`.*  If you wanted it to be an `int` you would need to explicitly do `int(x)` (which will raise `ValueError` if the string is non-numeric).

Comment: it says that it is missing a positional argument "name"

Comment: Whoops, forgot to remove the `name` parameter.  Fixed.

Comment: thank you @samwise